# What's the support for quaternions in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, opengl-es, quaternions

Considering modern OpenGL ( 3.x, 4.x, ES 2 and 3, WebGL ) and modern GLSL, what is the status of the support for quaternions vs the support for matrices ?

I'm finding more and more modern algorithms and papers that most of the times completely bypass matrix representations and only speak in terms of quaternions, especially the ones about lighting, but I still have to find any trace of quaternions inside OpenGL or any OpenGL ARB extension.

What's the status of quaternions for this Khronos standard ?

Comment: You can implement your own quaternions and use `vec4` for storage. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonexistent, you can pass them into the shaders as a vec4 but you'll have to implement the application of the quat rotation to a vector yourself.

Besides that you still need to pass in a vec3 translation and the projection parameters.

Most of the time it's faster to create the equivalent matrix from the quat plus translation pls projection and pass in the mat4 instead. Largely because multiplying a mat4 with a vector is faster (and better optimized in hardware) than applying the same rotation as a quat, and if you do enough of it the mat4 wins in speed even accounting the effort needed to transform the quat into the mat4 representation.

Comment: there is some good reason to not offer quaternions ? I read some papers that show that quaternions offer even better compression if compared to matrices, so why vendors or the ARB don't just add that ?

Comment: because most of the time matrices are only uploaded once as a uniform and they are just more flexible; you cannot represent a projection, translation, scale or a shear with just a quat

Comment: meh ... yes but quaternions are more friendly than matrices, at least for me, the fact that matrices are more flexible doesn't mean that quaternions should be off the API list. So you are basically saying that if I have a quaternion I have to compute values from the CPU side and I can't do anything on the GPU ?

Comment: @user2485710 no you can do your quat math on the GPU you just have to implement it yourself, it takes a few dot and cross products but it's perfectly doable.

Comment: yes, but it would be a "generic" dot and cross product, with a primitive data type you can optimize things inside GPU registers/drivers; it's still an overhead that I can't believe it's still there in 2014. Anyway if there is nothing available I'll find another way. Thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 actually [with `res = vector + cross(2*quat.xyz, (cross(quat.xyz, vector)+quat.w*vector)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Performance_comparisons) you can apply the rotation to a vector with 2 cross products

Comment: @user2485710: Quaternions are great if you have to *store* a lot of individual rotations. But they're a PITA if you have to use them in a transformation heirarchy because between you've to do the full calculation for each transformation step. With matrices you can coalesce a whole chain of transformations into one single matrix. So what you win in space savings with a quaternion is overcompensated by their numerical complexity. Also as soon, as you have to chain up 2 rotations and 2 translations also the space savings vanish.

Comment: @datenwolf you *can* concatenate quaternions, it's what the quaternion multiplication is for

Comment: @ratchetfreak: But you can't concatenate quaternions with translations. It's trivial to do with matrices. For example `M = R_1 · T_1 · R_2 · T_2`, where `R_n` are rotations and `T_n` are translation matrices. If you want to transform a vector by that transformation chain, you just have to multiply it with M. If you use quaternions, you have to follow through each individual step in the transformation chain, i.e. `v' = q_2 · (t_2 + q_1 · (t_1 + v))` – or even further deep recursions, depending on the length of your transformation chain. That variation of operators required is the problem.

Comment: @datenwolf but you can apply the translation vector with the later quaternions and add them together so you get: `M = R_1 · R_2 · (T_1 * R_2) · T_2` and you can combine the R_1 and R_2 rotations and the (T_1 * R_2) and T_2 translations into just a pair of vec4. It's the same as what happens when you multiply mat4 if you look at it as a mat3 rotation and vec3 translation. or just use dual quaternions

Comment: @ratchetfreak: True, but remember, this is all extra work, that has to be done. Quaternions are an excellent choice for certain operations, like interpolation rotations, as you need it in animation systems. But when you want to get things on the screen, you want to keep the amount of work to be done by the GPU small. So if you can compress and coalesce the way your animation system works with quaternions: Do it! But know their limitations. Crytek for example uses a very clever method of quaternion compression in their skinning animation system. Google for "Crytek QTangent".

Answer (score 0):

Still nonexistent after 8 years. I just like to add that there at least is `dot` and `cross`, so an implementation can be written like this:

```c
vec4 mul(vec4 l, vec4 r)
{
    return vec4(l.w * r.xyz + r.w + l.xyz + cross(l.xyz, r.xyz), l.w * r.w - dot(l.xyz, r.xyz));
}

vec4 invert(vec4 q)
{
    return vec4(-q.xyz, q.w) / dot(q, q);
}
```

I don't know if there's a performance gain in doing this.